# vim substitute function with s/

Tags: vim

I'm trying to execute the following

```
%s/foo/\=substitute(getline('.'),'bar','','g')
```

to this example

```
this is a foo cool bar
```

what I would like it to return is

```
this is a bar cool bar
```

but it's returning

```
this is a this is a foo cool  cool bar
```

meaning the whole line is returned not just the matched regexp in the substitute() function

am I missing something?

I'm aware of the split() function and sed implementation, but I want it in substitute()

Comment: do you want to swap foo and bar? or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why `substitute()`?

why not simply `:s/foo/bar/` ?

anyway, both ugly commands should work ... :(

```
:%s/foo/\=substitute(submatch(0),".*","bar","g")/

:%s/.*/\=substitute(submatch(0),"foo","bar","g")/
```

if you prefer to do it only with functions, this works too:

```
:%call setline(line('.'),substitute(getline('.'),'foo','bar','g'))
```

Comment: if I wanted to put '\([''"]\)\(.\{-}\)\1' instead of bar, how do I escape it?

Comment: @Ali can you please put everything (all your requirements) in your question once? not in 100 comments?

Comment: well i'm trying, I did that in the last question, but it seems the only way I can get my point though is going one step at the time, anyway I just need that as my final requirement and then I can edit the question with all the stuff all together, I'm sorry for this and thanks a lot for your great help :)

Comment: @Ali if you describe your problem over 100 comments, say, someone comes, he has to read all your comments under each answer, also he needs to keep an eye on the timestamp because he has to know the comment(requirements) order, it changes from comment to comment. Who will do that for you? Do you think you will get good answer in this way? well, just a suggestion...

Comment: thanks a lot Kent, as I said I will try to edit the main question and add all the requirements and solutions together :), it's my bad I can't seem to put what I need in words I guess...